# Jest Enzyme setState of memoryRouter dependant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, jestjs

I have a task to test React component that dependent of `BrowserRouter` component somewhere in the upper level. As far as I know `BrowserRouter` passes route object into props of any child, grandchild etc.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Program from './Program';

export default class Programs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      programs: [
        /** example */
        { id: 10, name: 'Golden Knights' },
        { id: 20, name: 'Silver Lords' },
        { id: 30, name: 'Wooden Kings' },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { programs } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul className="programs">{/*<-- add class "att-programs"*/}
        {
          programs.map(
            program => <Program
              key={program.id}
              program_id={program.id}
              program_name={program.name}
            />,
          )
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to test this component independently, I get an error: `Cannot read property 'route' of undefined`. To workaround this problem, I wrap my element into `MemoryRouter` component and my test looks following:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Programs from '../../src/components/Programs';

describe('<Programs />', () => {
  it('Renders list for any child from state', () => {

    const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter><Programs /></MemoryRouter>);
    const programs = wrapper.find(Programs);
    expect(programs.length).toBe(1);
    programs.setState({
      programs: [
        { id: 1, name: 'qwe' },
        { id: 2, name: 'asd' },
        { id: 3, name: 'zxc' },
      ],
    });

    expect(wrapper.find('li').length).toBe(3);
    expect(wrapper.find('a[href="/player/1"]').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Now I have another problem: `ReactWrapper::setState() can only be called on the root`

Please help me figure out how do I mock router but stay able to define `setState` on the testing component?

Comment: Did you think about maintaining that state somewhere else (e.g. Redux)? That way state would be passed into your component as properties -> 100% testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not to update internal state of component directly. Yo are ways going to manipulate that state somehow (or you are planning to). So use these mechanisms during testing. E.g. you might want to consider clicking on buttons via `wrapper.simulate("click")` and change the state that way. After that, you can verify that state transition was correct.

Comment: Moving to props from state helped! Thank you!